# How to memorize the second quantization form of the two-body interaction term?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, second-quantization

Suppose the two-body interaction potential is $V (x , y )$. The second-quantization form of the interaction hamiltonian is

$$ H_{int} = \frac{1}{2}\iint dx dy \psi^\dagger(x) \psi^\dagger(y) \psi(y) \psi(x) V(x, y) . $$

How to memorize it?

Why isn't it

$$ H_{int} = \frac{1}{2}\iint dx dy \psi^\dagger(x)  \psi(x) \psi^\dagger(y) \psi(y) V(x, y) ?  $$

Comment: The ordering in second quantization is important because it may lead to divergences. For example in your last expression you will have a term $V(x_i,x_i)$ for any $i\in{1,\dotsc,n}$ when acting on the $n$-particle wavefunction. For a Coulomb interaction however, $V(x_i,x_i)=\infty$. Normal ordering with creators on the left and annihilators on the right is often the only possible choice in second quantized systems.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first Hamiltonian is hermitian while the second one is not. Remember that $(AB)^{\dagger} = B^{\dagger}A^{\dagger}$

Comment: It is symmetric if $V$ is symmetric (as it should be).